# Best Way to Design this Locus Class

Tags: python, oop

Context: Hello to anyone who looks at this question. I am a beginning python coder (2 weeks going strong!) and I believe I initially designed my classes poorly and am asking for help on a good way to re-design the fundamental one (in Locus.py).

Background: The project has 4 classes so far which can be found here (https://github.com/asriley/HalfSiblings). The very base class **Locus** has  a tuple to represent an allele of genetic data (a,b). The next class, **Individual** has a list of alleles: [(a,b),(c,d),(a,e),(f,d)]. **In general though, we have n individuals and l loci for each individual.**

Sample Data: 7 individuals(rows) with 3 loci (cols)

```
1,1 5,3 4,3
1,2 4,7 3,7
2,3 3,6 5,4
2,4 7,4 4,9
3,6 8,9 3,0
6,5 4,8 0,0
7,7 7,7 7,9
```

I am trying to figure out how to design this class to incorporate it in other classes (Especially Individual) because eventually I have to use networkx to build graphs on the data.

A full snippet of the Locus class and the current error is given:

```
class Locus:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.alleles = ()
    def get_alleles(self):
        return self._alleles    
    def set_alleles (self,x, y):
        if x and y:
            self._alleles = (x,y)
    alleles = property (get_alleles, set_alleles)

l1 = Locus()
l1.set_alleles(1,2)
l1.set_alleles(2,3)
print (l1.get_alleles()) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Locus.py", line 13, in <module>
  l1 = Locus()
  File "Locus.py", line 4, in __init__
  self.alleles = ()
TypeError: set_alleles() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Can anyone assist with how I should properly handle this class?

File parsing is done in one of the other classes from the github link. So thats not an issue here. Eventually, I want to send a 2D list of Individuals  (containing the genetic Locus info) to the other classes.

Comment: The traceback doesn't match the actual code; there is not call to `self.set_alleles()` on that line. Do restart your interpreter if you changed the module code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have the same message when I re-ran it.

Comment: What I was missing was the `property()` line. Property setters can't take multiple value argument values.

Comment: Either stick with a getter and setter function, or use a property, but then you need to accept a *single object* every time you assign to the name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So before I was using the 'at' property keyword for the getters and setters, should I go back to that? Or is there another way to do the getter and setter? Im mostly concerned with the setting of a tuple here.

Comment: Your question is otherwise too broad; you could edit this question to focus on the immediate problem, but we generally can't do whole project reviews or give broad advice on OOP design. A question about why you get the error you do get is excellent, but that requires some editing here.

Comment: The `@property` and `@alleles.setter` decorator syntax is syntactic sugar. It's more readable in my opinion, but not the solution to your problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you want to use the @property decorator to get/set tuples on the Locus class, here's one possible way to do that:

```
class Locus:

    @property
    def alleles(self):
        return self._alleles

    @alleles.setter
    def alleles(self, value):
        try:
            x, y = value

            # ... Tuple processing goes here ...

            self._alleles = (x, y)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("(x,y) tuple expected")


l1 = Locus()
l1.alleles = (1, 2)
l1.alleles = (2, 3)
print(l1.alleles)
```

Comment: when you assign `l1.alleles = whatever`, that whatever is value. For instance, `l1.alleles = (1,2)`, the tuple (1,2) would be value. And when doing x,y = value you're unpacking the tuple, if it isn't unpacked correctly you'd get an exception. I'd recommend you take a look to this tutorial [https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php), it explain the basics quite well